# Search and replace a string having special characters in a file using Perl

Tags: perl

Search and replace a string in a file using Perl.
I have a .txt file. where i need to search and replace a string.
i code i have is working fine for string not having special characters.but for the string containing special characters like (?,=,:: ) is not working with this code.

Problem statement image

[image]

Code i am using and expected results

[image]

Comment: Please, edit your question to [format properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) everything and take the time to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you please review. thanks

Comment: Please add code etc. as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Perl's built-in function `quotemeta` to escape all special  characters in your search string. See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html